# "unconstrained type parameter" for `impl From<Struct> for T` when `impl Struct` works fine

Tags: rust

The polars library implements the following method to convert it into an array:

```rust
impl DataFrame {
    pub fn to_ndarray<N>(&self) -> Result<Array2<N::Native>>
    where
        N: PolarsNumericType,
        N::Native: num::Zero + Copy,
    {}
}
```

I want to make this more usable by using this function to implement a trait:

```rust
impl<N> From<DataFrame> for Array2<N::Native>
    where
        N: PolarsNumericType,
        N::Native: num::Zero + Copy
{}
```

This gives me:

```
129 | impl<N> From<DataFrame> for Array2<N::Native>
    |      ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

This is a well known problem with a million questions about it.

Can someone explain in English why the compiler is confused here?

It seems to me like everything is constrained: a `DataFrame` can be converted into any `Array2<N>`, subject to a few traits. I suppose this means the output type is generic, but this is also true of the original struct `impl`. How is my trait less constrained?

Comment: *with a million questions about it* — like **what**? Link to them and explain **what** you don't understand about those answers. Otherwise, any answerer is likely to just give you the *exact same answer* you've already read, wasting both of your times.

Comment: For anyone that does not know polars, the same question can also be asked independent of this library: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2662106e6966251543318689574b8acb) (PhantomData is just there to silence the compiler about this struct not using its generic parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the trait implementation is generic over all `Array2<N::Native>`, and `N::Native` is an *associated type*, not just the parameter itself.

It is possible for several different implementations of the trait `PolarsNumericType` to exist, all of which have the same `Native` type. Thus, the trait implementations for those `N`s would have the same `Self` type, and it would be ambiguous which one should be used.

Let me illustrate the conflict with a standalone toy example:

```rust
trait TypedNumber {
    type Raw: Copy;
    fn format_raw(x: Self::Raw) -> String;
}

struct Dollars(i64);
impl TypedNumber for Dollars {
    type Raw = i64;
    fn format_raw(x: i64) -> String {
        format!("${}.{:02}\n", x / 100, x % 100)
    }
}

struct Time(i64);
impl TypedNumber for Time {
    type Raw = i64;
    fn format_raw(x: i64) -> String {
        format!("{}m{:02}s\n", x / 60, x % 60)
    }
}

struct Report(String);
impl<N: TypedNumber> Into<Report> for &[N::Raw] {
    fn into(self) -> Report {
        Report(self.into_iter().copied().map(N::format_raw).collect())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let numbers: Vec<i64> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let report: Report = (&numbers).into();
    
    // Should this print money or time?
    println!("{}", report.0);
}
```

Here, `TypedNumber` corresponds to your `PolarsNumericType`, and my `N::Raw` corresponds to your `N::Native`. Using this trait and the `Into` impl, we can *attempt* to perform an operation using the trait, but it's ambiguous which implementation of the trait should be used.

On the other hand, if you write the conversion as a function (whether inside `impl DataFrame` or not, `N` will be **a parameter to the function,** so the caller can (and must, in this situation) specify it at the call site, and the program can compile:

```rust
fn report<N: TypedNumber>(data: &[N::Raw]) -> String {
    data.into_iter().copied().map(N::format_raw).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let numbers: Vec<i64> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{}", report::<Dollars>(&numbers));
    println!("{}", report::<Time>(&numbers));
}
```

---

To avoid this problem, you'll need to introduce *some* opportunity for the `N` to be specified. Unfortunately, I don't think that there's a good way to do that — the most you could do is introduce some sort of wrapper type which has `N` as a type parameter, but *then you'd still need to specify N somehow*, and so you'd end up writing a two-step conversion like `ArrayConvert::<N>::from(data_frame).into()`, which is *less* tidy than the existing `to_ndarray<N>()` function.

However, I'm not especially familiar with `polars`, so there might be some detail of that library that could allow a better solution.

Comment: Very helpful answer, I really didn't realise the associated type was causing the issue here. However I actually tried using the turbofish operator but it didn't help. My impl won't even compile as is, it's not the use of the function that's the issue.

Comment: But also I wonder if you could offer a solution as it's not clear to me how to clear up this constraint

Comment: @Migwell I've added some discussion of that to my answer. I don't think there's a solution that improves on `to_ndarray`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a little bit. But also my other question in the OP was about why this is allowed for the struct `impl` and not for my trait `impl`. I still don't understand this.

Comment: After rereading your explanation I think I understand now. If we want to convert a `DataFrame` into an `Array<f64>`, we need to call `.to_ndarray::<N>`, but there are multiple `N` we could choose to do this conversion that will result in an `f64` array. So it's unconstrained.

Comment: @Migwell Yes, that's right. I've edited to clarify that my `fn report` example is meant to be about the situation you called “struct impl” (the precise term is “inherent implementation” as opposed to “trait implementation”, by the way).